# Regarding macros

Tags: c, macros

may i know what is the problem in using the below x-macro code

```
#define FILL_BUFF_1 (int *)(0x01, 0x02)
#define FILL_BUFF_2 (int *)(0x03, 0x04)

#define X(a,b)

#define LOOK_UP \
     X(0x13, FILL_BUFF_1), \
     X(0x14, FILL_BUFF_2)

#undef X

#define X(a,b) a
int pid_table[2] = {LOOK_UP};
#undef X

#define X(a,b) b

int *pid_buff_ptr[2] = {LOOK_UP};

void main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d ", (pid_buff_ptr+0));  // displays 0x02

    printf("%d ", (pid_buff_ptr+1));  // displays 0x04

    printf("%d " ,*(pid_buff_ptr[0] + 1)); // doesnt work
}
```

How can I make the above code to access other elements in the buffer?

Comment: this has to be homework. Nobody would seriously want to write code as convoluted as that...

Comment: i've seen worse in the business world...

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: It may or it may not be homework, but I think inquisitive thinks that the first two lines define initialized arrays, which is the source of his/her problem.

Comment: gcc wont compile the line "int *pid_buff_ptr[2] = {LOOK_UP};" witch resolves to "int *pid_buff_ptr[2] = {(int *)(0x01, 0x02),(int *)(0x03, 0x04)"

Comment: Well guys this is not a homework as such.. i was trying to optimize the code by doing the above things.. 

@eaanon1: if the compilation fails, how come am getting some values dereferenced (in this case (pid_buff_ptr+0)) dereferences element 0x04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if I guessed correctly, you want to have the `pid_buff_ptr` variable contain an array of `int` values, not an array of `int *` values.

If that is the case, you need to change

```
#define FILL_BUFF_1 (int *)(0x01, 0x02)
#define FILL_BUFF_2 (int *)(0x03, 0x04)
```

to

```
#define FILL_BUFF_1 {0x01, 0x02}
#define FILL_BUFF_2 {0x03, 0x04}
```

Change the following:

```
int *pid_buff_ptr[2] = {LOOK_UP};
```

to

```
int pid_buff_ptr[][2] = {LOOK_UP};
```

To print, you would use something like:

```
printf("%d ", pid_buff_ptr[0][1]);
```

Of course, I could be wrong.

Now, some other comments:

- You need to `#include <stdio.h>` before using `printf()`.
- `main()` returns `int`.
- Since `main()` returns `int`, you should return an `int` from it.  Traditionally, `0` means success.
- I don't know what `_TCHAR` is, but if it is not an alias or `#define` for `char`, you might be in trouble.

Even with the above changes, I don't understand the need to do the trickery with the pre-processor.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Alok!! i have tried your code and it works.. btw, when i try to have declaration like "int pid_buff_ptr[][] = {LOOK_UP}", i am not able to do so.. what is my understanding is, you need not mention the column subscript of a 2D array, when u try initializing it in declaration itself.. am i right.. i need the above because, FILL_BUFF_N may be dynamic and need not contain only 2 elements

Comment: That's correct.  You can have only one dimension "free".  If you need more than two FILL_BUFF_* macros, you can easily do this by changing int pid_table[2] = {LOOK_UP}; to int pid_table[] = {LOOK_UP};, adding the required FILL_BUFF_* macros, and changing LOOK_UP macro.

But I still don't know what you're trying to do.  There is almost certainly an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

(Taking a wild stab at this just because it's been sitting here a while unanswered.)

In the last line, you appear to be dereferencing the value 0x03 as a pointer -- I suspect you are getting a SIGSEGV?

```
pid_buff_ptr[0] == 0x02
```

so

```
(pid_buff_ptr[0] + 1) == 0x03
```

so

```
*(pid_buff_ptr[0] + 1)
```

is dereferencing 0x03 as a pointer.

Comment: @william: Ya u r right.. my actual question is, how can i de-reference to get the value 0x03.. i dont understand why (pid_buff_ptr[0] + 1) is dereferencing 0x03, instead of memory location containing 0x03.. my understanding is, pid_buff_ptr[0] is the first element in the array, which is a pointer to the buffer (0x01, 0x03)